# What are some ways people deploy relational database changes using Node.js?

Tags: database, node.js, deployment, migration

I've been diving more and more into Node.js and hosting services like Heroku and Nodejitsu recently and have been trying to figure out how to best deploy database changes for postgres or mysql.

There are a few migration projects under npm that I can see; however, all seem to be really buggy or just not work.  I currently manage the Monarch migration project on npm, but it's currently buggy itself and my experiences developing such utilities are in other, more procedural, languages.

So what do people use to deploy changes to their databases on these environments?  What has worked for people?

I'm looking for a better understanding of what the current situation/process looks like.

Comment: @Xaade I don't understand your question.  If you mean "let programmers just handle it" - well that's what I'm trying to figure out HOW programmers would handle such.  What tools do they use?  What is their workflow?  It's difficult to locate guidance on this subject in the Node ecosystem at the moment.

Comment: @JamesEggers Xaade was wondering aloud if this question would be more suitable on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Usually you ask here if you have a specific problem coding something, understanding code, etc. You post on Programmers if you want more general information, like how to approach a problem, or what third party to use. Here is fact driven *timeless* answers, there is speculation, *time-sensitive*, and professional opinion. I'm not trying to comment on your question's quality, I'm just trying to get you better answers.

Comment: @Xaade I see.  Very good point and thanks for clarifying.  Too many sites to keep track.  If a moderator wanted to migrate it that works.

Comment: @Xaade - What 3rd party to use would be closed as not constructive.

Comment: I was looking for techniques more than tools since there's practically 0 guidance on this topic and am curious.  Very surprised that moderators closed this instead of migrating it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself but the Sequelize ORM supports migrations as of 1.3. http://sequelizejs.com/#migrations

Perhaps someone else can add details of their experience with it.